# Monitor OCX calls?

Tags: api, reverse-engineering, ocx

I have an OCX without documentation and need to use it.
I've figured out most of the stuff, but, is it possible to monitor all the calls and arguments made by one software to that OCX?
I've tried ProcessMonitor, APIMonitor and none of them give me that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but [WinApiOverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/) seems to support COM object calls monitoring:

http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/doc/com.htm

This is a pretty advanced tool, however, and you'll likely have to spend some time adding rules for your specific COM classes.